# como mando un correo con outlook en windows 10 desde una app en c#

Tags: c#, outlook

estoy haciendo una app en windows 10 que manda correos a traves de outlook, para ello estoy usando la libreria  Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library, el problema es que no consigo vincular outlook a la aplicacion, este es el codigo para mandarlo

```
private void enviarCorreoOutlook(string cuerpo, string destinatario)
        {
            try
            {
                var oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = 
              oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                var f =ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                var mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment att = mailItem.Attachments.Add(      
                imageSignaturePath,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem,
                null,
                "Firma");



                mailItem.Subject = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                mailItem.HTMLBody = "<body>"+cuerpo+"</body>";
                mailItem.To = destinatario;
                mailItem.Send();
            }



            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido enviar el correo a: "+destinatario);
            }
```

Comment: Por que usando outlook en lugar de usar clases nativas de .net?

Comment: no he usado mucho c# y se lo minimo pero me estoy guiando por lo que encuentro

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: siguiendo lo que ha escrito pikoh debajo de mi pregunta la respuesta a esta pregunta la resppnde este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp